# How do i loop through certain number of folders

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to loop through a folder that has 744 sub directories. How do i loop through only certain number of folders. Since i have 744 sub directories i would split this into half and loop through first 372 directories and then later on loop through rest of the 372 directories. I want to make sure i don't copy directories multiple times. Below is what i tried doing but i want to know what would be the effective way of doing this to avoid duplication.

```
for d in `ls -tr|tail -372`
do
echo $d
done
```

Comment: Pipe it to uniq?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your "avoid duplication" concern. Does your current solution result in duplication? Or are you trying to come up with a general solution that takes however many subdirectories you have and splits it into two halves?

Comment: @lurker just to add more there are chances that my folder structure would change in future so i am trying to come up with a general solution that would split subdirectories count into half. And when i do that i want to make sure that i don't see folder name multiple times

Comment: Ah ok, that makes sense. I'm also curious as to why you need to split them in half.

Comment: @BaileyKocin i never tried uniq but let me dig into that

Comment: **Never parse the output of `ls`!** You can [read here why](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-do-to-instead). Also it is unclear what you want to achieve. Why do you want to split the directories? Do you want them in chunks? Can you as well just execute them in parallel one-by-one without the range restriction?

Comment: It might be easier to get all of them listed into a temporary file first, then you can determine the count of lines you're dealing with (`wc -l`) and use that to get your two line counts. Unless you know it's always around 744 files, then use `tail -372` and `head -372` as you are currently. You can use `find` instead of `ls -tr`. `find` will include the path. `ls -tr` displays output with path headings, and probably not what you want.

Comment: @feliks i am trying to copy these folders using copy command in different servers. First 372 will be copied under one server and another 372 would be copied under different server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since my `xargs` answer didn't receive any feedback, here's another approach.

```
printf "%s\n" */ |
awk 'BEGIN { n=1; OFS="\t"
        split("first:second:third", destination, /:/) }
    (i++ % 372)=0 { ++n }
    { print destination[n], $0 }'
```

This will add a field in front of each directory name, which you can use to process the results further. Sample output:

```
first   directory1/
first   directory2/
first   directory3/
:
first   directory372/
second  directory373/
second  directory374/
:
second  directory743/
second  directory744/
```

So the field value `third` from the Awk script is never used, but I put it in anyway to demonstrate that this could easily be extended to do three-way partitions, or four-way or what have you.

You would use this e.g. by piping to

```
while IFS= read -r dest dir; do
    echo mv "dir" "$dest"
done
```

Unlike the `xargs -0` answer, this is not robust against arbitrary file names; in particular, directory names which contain newlines will not work correctly.

Actually a much better solution would be to split the files the other way -- i.e. for a two-way partition, print `first` on every other line, and `second` on every other. Then you don't have to hard-code the number of items, just the number of partitions.

```
printf "%s\n" */ |
awk 'BEGIN { OFS="\t"
        n = split("ernie:bert", host, /:/) }
    { print host[1+((NR-1)% n)], $0 }' |
while IFS= read -r server dir; do
    mkdir -p "$server"
    mv "$dir" "$server/"
done
```

Regardless of the number of directories, this splits them evenly into the directories `ernie` and `bert`, on the optimistic assumption that you (too) might have named your file servers after Sesame Street characters.

If you want to `scp` the directories instead of `mv` them, grouping them by server name would be a lot more efficient; but a simple `sort` takes care of that if necessary. (That's not the only reason we print the destination before each file name; it's also useful because then we don't have to worry that the directory names could contain our field separator.)

Comment: Great solution and i really thank you for taking time to answer my question. I was thinking different approach now that i am talking with you. What if i sort parent directory and then once i have sub-directories alphabetically then i would simply iterate through folders [A-M] and then [N-Z]

Comment: If the names are evenly alphabetically distributed, that should work fine. In many real-world scenarios that is not the case, though.

Comment: Yes in my use case names are evenly alphabetically distributed. Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can use `xargs` but this requires the 372 directory names to fit in one invocation (i.e. the directory names combined must not exceed `ARG_MAX`).

```
printf '%s\0' */ |
xargs -n 372 -r -0 sh -c '
    d=dest$$; mkdir "$d"; cp "$@" "$d"' _
```

This will generate a unique new directory with the prefix `dest` and a number for each batch of directories it copies. There are probably better ways to split the files (and calling `sh` from `xargs` is not exactly a newbie-friendly answer) but maybe this should at least give you some ideas.

In some more detail, `xargs -n 372` limits the number of arguments that get processed in one go, and the command you pass to `xargs` could be something a lot simpler; `xargs -n 372 cp -t fnord` would copy first 372 directories to `fnord`, then another 372; but in order for this to be actualy useful, we want the destination directory to change each time we call `xargs`, and so I put in a simple script which does that.

You also need to understand that 372 is a maximum, and if the directory names are really long, `xargs` could decide that it needs to pass fewer directories in order to not cross the "argument list too long" limit. But for your use case, on any remotely modern system, we are probably far below that limit anyway.

`xargs -0` and `cp -t` are GNU extensions, i.e. they should work on Linux out of the box, and you can install them on most other platforms; if you really need to support something like Solaris without installing external tools, that's going to be slightly more challenging.

---

Addendum: Here's a `xargs` implementation of the `ernie` & `bert` part of the Awk answer:

```
printf "%s\0" */ |
xargs -r -0 -n 2 sh -c '
    mkdir -p ernie bert
    mv "$1" ernie
    mv "$2" bert' _
```

There will be an ugly but harmless error message for the last item if you have an uneven number of input directories. There are obvious but inelegant ways to fix that, or elegant but obscure ones; but I prefer to keep this plain for now.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the argument to `xargs` could also easily be `sh -c 'for d; do echo "$d"; done' _` if that's really all you want. (Notice also the proper quoting of the variable interpolation.)